# How can I copy a Docker image fetched from the Internet and move it to a host not connected to the Internet?

Tags: docker

Say I want to get a Docker image (such as https://github.com/zettio/weave/blob/master/weaver/Dockerfile) downloaded and built from the Internet, but then take it to a computer not connected to the Internet, so that computer can run a container using it?

What files/directories would I need to archive to do that?

Comment: You could try and see if moving a container in `/var/lib/docker/containers/` does the trick. This should work for simple containers but if the container is dependable on other containers then it becomes messy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Save` it, copy the tar file to a USB, go to other computer and `load` it.

```
docker save -o image.tar image
```

then on other computer:

```
docker load -i image.tar
```